# Dimensions and useWindowDimensions React Native non-consistance

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using Expo and logging `Dimensions.get('window').height` and `useWindowDimensions().height` values. And when I reload the app via Expo I notice that there is about a 50% chance that I get 812 (normal behavior) and a 50% chance that I get 70 (weird behavior). Is there any way to get a consistent value of screen height in React Native? Or what should I check to fix `Dimensions.get('window').height` and `useWindowDimensions().height` inconsistency? Any advice would be appreciated

UPD: I noticed that it concerns only `.height` property. All the rest stay ok:

```
Object {
  "fontScale": 1,
  "height": 70,
  "scale": 3,
  "width": 375,
}
```

```
Object {
  "fontScale": 1,
  "height": 812,
  "scale": 3,
  "width": 375,
}
```

Any ideas on why can that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: change Dimensions.get('window') with Dimensions.get('screen'), it works consistent